# 'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, zip

I am trying the zip functionality on the windows host through command prompt.

When I run the command:

```bsh
zip -r folder.zip folder
```

It returns the error message:

> 'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I checked with environment variables also in there path also included like
`%SystemRoot%\system32`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

Windows doesn't have a command line Zip program, only a default windows explorer one. You will need to download a command line archiving program.

Try [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/).

Comment: These programs are already install like 7z, winzip, winrar. I need to do zip through command line. if you know how can i do this then please let me know.

Comment: Just google for the documentation. http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Answer (score 4):

Well, to use zip or unzip command from the command line using third party software like 7zip, you have to do below things

- Copy the 7-zip executable path and append it to the environment's PATH variable value
- Open Cmd new window and give the command as below

> **7z a folder.zip folder**

Comment: zip does not work, 7z.exe does "7z.exe a ...archivepath... /dir..../"